# Problem in Running the example CorDapp Could not create the DataSource: Unknown data type: "İNT"

Tags: corda

When I was trying to install and run the example CorDapp(https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html), there is an error 
Could not create the DataSource: Unknown data type: "İNT"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED İNT NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255), LABELS VARCHAR(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR(10)) [50004-197] [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED İNT NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255), LABELS VARCHAR(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR(10))]: Could not create the DataSource: Unknown data type: "İNT"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED İNT NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255), LABELS VARCHAR(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR(10)) [50004-197] [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED İNT NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255), LABELS VARCHAR(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR(10))

I think the problem is when creating table DATABASECHANGELOG SQL type INT is interpreted as İNT and the create table script could not be run.

The script is in liquibase XXXX.jar file.
When I open the file including the script there is no problem with the script. 
But when I run with  ./gradlew deployNodes command I receive the above error. 
I tried it on windows 10 and ubuntu 16.X but I encounter with the same error.
I need any help in running sample Corda application.

Comment: Which application are you trying to run from "https://github.com/corda/samples"?

In Corda Enterprise, DATABASECHANGELOG table is created by Liquibase runner.

Comment: Yes I donwloaded the code from that address(git clone https://github.com/corda/samples) .

Comment: Can you specify the application name i.e. yo-cordapp, cordapp-example, obligation-cordapp etc from the samples folder, that was run by you?

Comment: I try to run cordapp-example.Branch v4

Comment: When I run release V3 it does not give any error on database creation scripts but give error on log4j. 804 Task worker for ':' ERROR Delete contains invalid attributes "IfFileName", "IfLastModified"

Comment: But for release v4 it gives error both on database creation script and log4j

Comment: I think the problem is related with gradlewrapper. If I use the gradlerwrapper for Release V3. Encoding problem does not exist but it gives compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how do you run into a database issue when you simply try to start the app. The H2 database is automatically populate when the nodes are built.

You can find a complete tutorial at: https://training.corda.net/prepare-and-discover/discover-example/#open-the-project